# Detect if Directory Assistance is enabled

Tags: ibm-domino, lotus-notes

I would like to detect if a specific Domino Server is configured to use Domino Directory Assistanse.

So far I am aware of two areas to check:

1. Notes.ini (variable Names).

https://dominohilfe.de/customer/notesini.nsf/85255a87005060c585255a850068ca6f/e1719f98b3b090ddc1256b8d006a5a11?OpenDocument&Click=

As I understand if Names variable is defined in notes.ini it should always start within 'names' and then extra directories must follow. It seems I can simply check if length of Names variable is longer than 5 characters and if so - it means DA is configured on the server.

2. Field in server document: 'Directory assistance database name'

[image]

If it is not empty, than I can say 'Directory assistance' is configured on the server.

Are my statements valid?

Thanks.

Comment: Almost correct: the names= - entry is NOT called directory assistance, although it does almost the same. The names.ini entry predates the Directory assistance and was made obsolete by da. But still there are servers that are (wrongly) configured with notes.ini entry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "names="- entry in the notes.ini was the way to have multiple addressbooks up until Version 6 when the "directory assistance" was introduced.

So technically the notes.ini predates the directory assistance and became obsolete when DA was introduced.

But nevertheless I found a server recently that still has the notes.ini entry in place, so it seems that not all admins got the point about DA and changed their setup.

Other than that nitpicky point about naming the feature you are right: These two are the places to check if other addressbooks are configured on the server.

Instead of checking the server document (which may have been changed recently without rebooting so that da is not enabled yet) you could also send the console command "show xdir" to find out if DA is enabled and working.